# How to change specific img src on click of individual images that have the same id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im trying to change the source of an individual image on a div click. The problem is that I have many divs that have the same image, and images with the same id. Therefore, when I click the first, it changes, but when I click on the second, the first one changes.

I'm not yet very good at jquery, but I can imagine a "This" would help? Or do I need to give a different id to each img?

To see the problem heres a jsfiddle > https://jsfiddle.net/gfmyukaL/

I want each img to change individually based on its host div.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("folder").src == "http://somethingsomething.online/folder.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("folder").src = "http://somethingsomething.online/folderopen.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("folder").src = "http://somethingsomething.online/folder.png";
        }


    }
</script>


<img style="position:absolute; bottom:2vh; width:100vw;" src="images/constuction_bar.gif" alt="under construction">

<div class="container">                                     
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" onclick="changeImage()" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="menu"><img id="folder" src="folder.png"> Parent Directory</div></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a class="test" onclick="changeImage()" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="menu"><img id="folder" src="folder.png"> Parent Directory</div></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a class="test" onclick="changeImage()" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="menu"><img id="folder" src="folder.png"> Parent Directory</div></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a class="test" onclick="changeImage()" tabindex="-1" href="#"><div class="menu"><img id="folder" src="folder.png"> Parent Directory</div></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>              
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>

<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}
.menu:hover{
  background-color:yellow;
}
*{
  font-family:monospace;
}

.test{
  border: red;
    border-color: aquamarine;
    border-width: 6px;
    /* background-color: blue; */
    border-style: dotted;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

li{
  margin-left:5vw;
}

.dropdown-menu {
display:contents;
margin-left: 2vw;

}

.container{
  margin:0px;
  width:40vw;
  padding:0px;
}

#folder{
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px red) drop-shadow(-1px -1px 1px green);
}

</style>
```

Comment: So the first problem you have here is the same ID, ID should always be unique on same page

Comment: @Atul Does that mean the only thing that will fix it is to manually give each div / img a unique id and make javascript look for each one?

Comment: so basic use you want, is to change the folder icon on the base of its child open or not? right?

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML element. You won’t be able to select any of those elements but the first one _by ID_ otherwise. _“Does that mean the only thing that will fix it is to manually give each div a unique id and make javascript look for each one?”_ - not necessarily, there are other ways to select or “find” elements using JavaScript, it doesn’t always have to be by an ID.

Comment: @Atul That's correct

Comment: having unique id for each element would solve your problem i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code a bit, now check this. I have basically have all your folder close by CSS, you can open these if you want by CSS, tell me if you need it, modify CSS as per your need, The idea is to change the URL of image only, nothing else.

```
  var closedFolder = "http://somethingsomething.online/folder.png"
  var openFolder = "http://somethingsomething.online/folderopen.png"
  $('.test').click(function(){
     var nextMenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
     nextMenu.toggle();
     if($(nextMenu).is(':visible')){
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', openFolder);
     }else {
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', closedFolder);
     }
 });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var closedFolder = "http://somethingsomething.online/folder.png"
  var openFolder = "http://somethingsomething.online/folderopen.png"
  $('.test').click(function(){
    var nextMenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
    nextMenu.toggle();
    
    if($(nextMenu).is(':visible')){
      $(this).find('img').attr('src', openFolder);
    }else {
       $(this).find('img').attr('src', closedFolder);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
    }

    .menu:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    * {
        font-family: monospace;
    }

    .test {
        border: red;
        
    }

    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -1px;
    }

    li {
        margin-left: 5vw;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
        display: contents;
        margin-left: 2vw;

    }

    .container {
        margin: 0px;
        width: 40vw;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #folder {
        filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px red) drop-shadow(-1px -1px 1px green);
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu {
      display: none;
    }
    #mainMenu > .dropdown-submenu, #mainMenu {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="mainMenu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                        <div class="menu"><img src="http://somethingsomething.online/folder.png"> Parent Directory</div>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                                <div class="menu"><img src="http://somethingsomething.online/folder.png"> Parent Directory</div>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                                <div class="menu"><img src="http://somethingsomething.online/folder.png"> Parent Directory</div>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                                        <div class="menu"><img src="http://somethingsomething.online/folder.png"> Parent Directory</div>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

. I hope this would help you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna look at how you did it, but it seems to work perfectly!